# Structure constructor in other structure

Tags: c++

I am trying to create Voronoi diagram for some given points. Each points have different attributes and I want to denote it as color. To map my own Point structure with Boost Point concept, I have written some code. I have the following setup:

```
struct Point {
  double a;
  double b;
  Point(double x, double y) : a(x), b(y) {}
};

// This Point structure is mapped to Boost Point concept. Code emitted
```

I have another structure as :

```
struct Point_Collection {
  Point xy(double x, double y);
  short color;

};
```

Visual Studio created an automatic definition as :

```
Point Point_Collection::xy(double x, double y)
{
    return Point();
}
```

Now if I try to instantiate an object of Point_collection as:

```
std::vector<Point_Collection> *test;
test = new std::vector<Point_Collection>();

Point_Collection xy_color;

for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
    xy_color.xy(rand() % 1000, rand() % 1000);
    xy_color.color = rand() % 17;
    test->push_back(xy_color);
}
```

I get an error.

```
 error C2512: 'Point': no appropriate default constructor available
```

Can someone point me in the right direction why is this happening?

Comment: Whats error you get?

Comment: What's purpose of `Point xy(double x, double y);` declaration as part of member of `Point_Collection`? Why cant you just declare `Point xy`.

Comment: `xy` is a member function, you would have to write `xy_color.xy(.....);` . And provide a body for the function

Comment: Please clarify in addition to the exact error message: Did you really want to declare a member function called `xy` that takes two `double`s and returns a `Point`? In your third snippet are you trying to access the `xy` and `color` members of `xy_color`? If not, what are `xy` and `color` in that context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Point xy(double x, double y);` declares a **member function** in `Point_Collection` that is identified by `xy`, accepts two doubles and returns a `Point` object by value.

If you want a simple aggregate that holds a point, the C++11 and onward way would be to define it like this:

```
struct Point_Collection {
  Point xy;
  short color;
};

Point_Collection xy_color{ { rand()%100, rand()%100 }, static_cast<short>(rand()%16)};
```

The above is a simple aggregate initialization using value initialization syntax. You should prefer it for two reasons:

1. It will not allow narrowing conversions. (Which `int` to `short` is, therefore the cast).
2. It's easy to implement. It requires no typing if your class has all public members.

(Also `rand` has better alternatives in C++11, check out the header `<random>`)

---

If you don't have access to C++11, then you can either write a constructor for `Point_Collection`.

```
struct Point_Collection {
  Point xy;
  short color;

  Point_Collection(Point xy, short color)
    : xy(xy), color(color) {}
};

Point_Collection xy_color (Point(...,...), ...);
```

Or use aggregate initialization with more verbose syntax:

```
struct Point_Collection {
  Point xy;
  short color;
};

Point_Collection xy_color = { Point(rand()%100, rand()%100), rand()%16 };
```

(Since the above is C++03, `rand()%16` will be silently converted to `short`, despite it being narrowing).

Comment: Can you please suggest me a resource where I can read information like this about C++. Also , honestly I did not understand the mapping of my Point structure to Boost Point concept, I just copy pasted from Boost documentation and it worked. Where I can learn those basics?

Comment: @MojoJojo - The proper way to learn C++ is from a [good, vetted, book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Thanks, was just going through that thread. Seems I have lot to learn. Thanks again.